# How many places behind the comma does one need to get correct rouding

Tags: mysql, math, rounding

Say you want to give a 5 € discount on a product that costs 60 €.

This equals a discount of 0.08333... or 8.333... %

When calculating backwards, I would calculate:

- round(60 * 0.083333, 2) = 5,00
- round(60 * 0.08333, 2) = 5,00
- round(60 * 0.0833, 2) = 5,00
- round(60 * 0.083, 2) = 4,98

Q: How many places behind the comma are necessary to get accurate number (for monteary transactions) with any amount of discount on any base price?

or in practical terms, when storing discounts in a MySQL table, what should my decimal(x,y) type parameters be?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the cumulative error is smaller than 1/2 cent or 0.005. The relative accuracy of the intermediate results needs to reflect that. If the prices contained in the computations are all below `10^k = 10^(k+2)` cent, this requires a relative accuracy of `0.5*10^(-k-2)` or at least `k+3` significant digits in all intermediate numbers.

Note that errors accumulate in every step of the calculation, in first order additively, so that when a calculation has multiple steps, the relative accuracy of the calculation needs to be adjusted down resp. the number of significant digits up by `log10(s)` for `s` steps.

In your example, `k=2` with `2` steps with rounded results, so that the intermediate result should have at least `5` significant digits to be sure to get the correct result.